# Screen recording with Quicktime only puts 360p quality video on YouTube

Tags: quicktime, youtube

I used QuickTime's screen recorder to record a 23 minute video of a section of my Macbook screen and it uploaded my video to 360p as the highest selectable quality on YouTube. How can I change the quality it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although QuickTime does give you the option in File > Export to export as 720p, it was just a matter of waiting another 20 minutes for the video to be upgraded to 720p.